# Show a text in the SWF from a class in AS3 (flash)

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

i have a dynamic text on my scene called testtext, in the accions i can show a text simple by testtext.text = "my content";

But now i want to do this from a class, if i copy directly the instruccion like i do normaly it doest work. What i need to do? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your class is self contained and not aware of the outside world. You will need to create a function that you can feed it the textfield name so it can then target it.

so from inside your class create a public function like this:

```
public var myTextField:TextField;

public function setTextTarget(tf:TextField):void
{
   myTextField = tf;
}

public function updateText(msg:String):void
{
  myTextField.text = msg;
}
private function randomFunction():void
{
  // update the textfield from an internal function
  myTextField.text = "text here"
}
```

So in your FLA file where you have imported your class it will look something like this:

```
var myClass:ClassName = new ClassName;
myClass.setTextTarget(TextFieldName);
myClass.updateText("text here");
```